# Converting a Rails 2 route to Rails 3 route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I'm working thru one of the [Active Merchant examples at Railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/145-integrating-active-merchant), and I'm having trouble converting one of the routes to Rails 3

Here is the Rails 2 snippet [(reference)](https://github.com/railscasts/145-integrating-active-merchant/blob/master/store/config/routes.rb):

```
ActionController::Routing::Routes.draw do |map|
  map.resources :orders

  map.current_cart 'cart', :controller => 'carts', :action => 'show', :id => 'current'

  map.resources :line_items
  map.resources :carts
  map.resources :products
  map.resources :categories
  map.root :products
end
```

And here is my Rails 3 equivalent:

```
ActionController::Routing::Routes.draw do |map|
  resources :orders

  map.current_cart 'cart', :controller => 'carts', :action => 'show', :id => 'current'

  resources :line_items
  resources :carts
  resources :products
  resources :categories
  root :products
end
```

I am having problems figuring out how to translate the map.current_cart route.  I've tried making it a resource, mapping it and matching it.  All throw an undefined variable or method error.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the blog:--

```
http://active-merchant-rails3.blogspot.in/2014/05/create-new-rails-3.html
```

I have created a github repository on active merchant on rails 3.2.

```
https://github.com/shamsulsham89/active_merchant_rails3.2
```

Comment: That seems to work, except for when I try to call current_cart from another controller or a helper.. I get an 'undefined local variable or method 'current_cart' '

Comment: I have added a github repo. Campare the changes for rails 3.2